# ¿Cómo definir o expresar en español las palabras "slicing" y "broadcasting" usadas en Python?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, informática, inglés

¿Cómo podemos definir o expresar en el lenguaje español, las palabras "*slicing*" y "*broadcasting*" que se usan en Python?

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: La herramienta "Slice" de Photoshop está traducida como "Sector". *Slicing* sería *sectorizar*.

Comment: Creo que en Python no podemos relacionar “slicing” como sectorizar, ya que el uso de sectorizar puede ser ambiguo, por lo menos en este lenguaje de programación. Sin embargo, considero interesante el conocer lo que representa “slicing” en otros paquetes de cómputo. Se agradece tu aportación @Danielillo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Cómo definir o expresar en español las palabras "slicing" y "broadcasting" usadas en Python?

---

- **Slicing** - "Operador de Corte" (Extractor de una secuencia o Extractor secuencial). La expresión "slicing" hace referencia a la operación por medio de la cual se obtienen los elementos de una secuencia, así la función "Slice () " devuelve un objeto del segmento o cadena.

  Este "operador de corte" u "slicing" se utiliza para especificar como utilizar una secuencia o segmento de información dentro de listas o cadenas de caracteres.
- **Broadcasting** - "Difusión de Paquetes Multidimensional". Es una estrategia o método de planificación de la biblioteca "numpy" de Python, para operar y hacer más eficientes los cálculos con matrices multidimensionales, (array, conocidos también como "arreglos" debido a una mala traducción).

***Broad** + **Casting**, (Difusión de Posición + Reparto), en este caso "Broad" se refiere a un tipo de archivo de posición donde se depositan los datos en un proceso de selección, agrupamiento y reparto de los mismos (Casting) y desde donde se expande o difunde la información a partir de otras aplicaciones*.

Comment: Respecto a “slicing” creo que es más comprensible usar “extractor secuencial” que operador de corte, ya que este último puede crear confusión en el ámbito informático. En cuanto a “broadcasting”, muy interesante la definición de Broad + casting, la considero muy clara y completa. Agradezco tu respuesta @Diego

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo, quedo agradecido contigo. Gracias.

Comment: Antes de publicar esta pregunta en "Spanish Language", a mis alumnos yo les explicaba que "slicing" lo podrían también reconocer como una segmentación de datos por medio de índices (segmentación con índices). ¿Consideran que también podría ser correcto referirse de esta manera a "slicing"?

Answer (score 2):

Del libro *Aprende Python*, de Sergio Delgado Quintero:

> **Slicing**. "Troceado". 
> **Broadcasting**. "Difusión".

Comment: En algunos libros de Python, redactados en el lenguaje español, también se refieren a "slicing" como rebanado y "broadcasting" como emisión. Creo que el uso de "troceado", "rebanado" y "difusión", "emisión"  contribuyen más a la confusión. Además considero que este es un claro ejemplo que no se pueden usar las traducciones literales de ciertas palabras en inglés a español, al menos en informática y por ello, es mejor expresar lo que hacen dichas técnicas de manipulación de datos en Python. De cualquier manera, agradezco tu aportación @karloswitt.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la respuesta de @Diego seguramente sea la más correcta, ambos términos tienen una traducción muy extraña que casi nadie usará para referirse a esos términos.

Creo que son más frecuentes las traducciones:

- *Slicing*: troceado
- *Broadcasting*: emisión/difusión